# How to fix Authorization issue in ANGULAR while accessing REST APIs

Tags: javascript, angular

I have authentication and authorization set in my API's and they are working fine from POSTMAN and .html file, same API's I'm consuming in my web application I could login but subsequent calls are getting 401 unauthorized error.

Difference which I found from postman and my application is cookie getting set as soon as authorization but same is not happening in ANGULAR(my web applicaton), do I need to set explicitly in headers, or is there any way to handle this.

through postman/browser it is setting cookie out of the box as request header 
`Cookie: customkey=s%3AKIwsT51lsPQieNCy9Tuyr4uhxBuVs3Mb.%2FDLzmp0IC68OSwFDDQEtoUml%2BWBQ6k0dwvPcTMGLKls`

Same If I try from ANGULAR is not allowed, reason I have ended up with 401 unathorized error

Comment: What version of Angular do you use?

Answer (score -1):

Should have some headers properties necessary to connect with backend service.

Take a look in headers tab in postman and try using it in Angular request.

Ex. using $http dependency:

```
$http({
 method: 'POST', // or get
 url: 'ENDPOINT',
 headers: {
   'Content-Type': 'buz',
   'x-auth': 'bla',
   'token': 'fuz',
 },
 data: { }
})
```

[Setting HTTP Headers documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#setting-http-headers)

Comment: Please can you be clearer on exactly what you're trying to achieve? What is the outcome? Are the headers not sent?